# How to delete multiple using checkbox with Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox, sql-delete

i am trying to delete values with check box using ajax call can any one help me out.

unable to find the error and one nore thing this is a template and i hav a feature of check all inbuilt so do need to change anyinbuilt code for check box
This is my listing form:

```
<form id="stafflistForm">
<input type="hidden" name="checkedids" value="<?php echo $staffResults['id_staff']; ?>">
<button id="deleteChecked"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
</form>
```

This my Ajax Script:

```
<script language="JavaScript">  
    $("#deleteChecked").click(function()
    {
        $("#delshowMessageDiv").hide();
        $("#delshowMessage").html('');
        $.ajax({
            url: "staffcontroller.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { delData : $("#stafflistForm").serialize(), 'action':'delete'},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if(response["success"]==true)
                {
                    $("#delshowMessageDiv").hide();
                    $("#delshowSuccessMessageDiv").show();
                    $("#delshowSuccessMessage").html(response["message"]);
                    }else{
                    $("#delshowMessageDiv").show();
                    $("#delshowMessage").html(response["message"]);
                }   
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                $("#hshowMessageDiv").show();
                $("#hshowMessage").html("OOPS! Something Went Wrong Please Try After Sometime!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });     
</script>
```

And this is my controller page:

```
else if($_REQUEST['action']=='delete'){
    $delids=explode(",",$_REQUEST["checkedids"]);
    $count=count($delids);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $delQuery= $conn->query("DELETE FROM os_staff WHERE id_staff=".$delids[$i]);
    }
        if($delQuery){
        $response['message'] = "<strong>Success!</strong>Staff Deleted Successfully.";
        $response['success'] = true;
        }else{
        $response['message'] = "<strong>Warning!</strong> Staff Not Deleted.Please Check Carefully..";
        $response['success'] = false;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Dont use html attribute `id` if you using it multipli `id="deleteChecked"`. Use class selector or data attribute instead. That should be help to solve your issue.

Comment: You can use the WHERE IN clause in SQL: `$delQuery= $conn->query("DELETE FROM os_staff WHERE staff IN ('9','7','6'));` Just change the value of your formats into this format ('9','7','6') you can use implode()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all:** Dont use html attribute id if you using it multipli id="deleteChecked". Use class selector or data attribute instead.

Here is a small script which show you how you can improve your code. 
That should be help you to solve your issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.delete-user').on('click', function(e) {
    // do here your ajax
    
    // this is just example
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.fa-trash-o {
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form class="stafflistForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="checkedids" value="<?php echo $staffResults['id_staff']; ?>">
        <button class="delete-user"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td>Tom</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form class="stafflistForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="checkedids" value="<?php echo $staffResults['id_staff']; ?>">
        <button class="delete-user"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td>Peter</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form class="stafflistForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="checkedids" value="<?php echo $staffResults['id_staff']; ?>">
        <button class="delete-user"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td>Son Goku</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form class="stafflistForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="checkedids" value="<?php echo $staffResults['id_staff']; ?>">
        <button class="delete-user"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td>Gozilla</td>
  </tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: He can also use `$("button#deleteChecked").click(function()`

Answer (score 1):

The PHP script should set the correct mime type via:

`header('Content-type: application/json');`

Besides that: Why do you have separate DIV containers for the error and success messages? Why not have one "feedback" div, which gets a CSS class which does the formating (based on error or success).